# fs does not download images

Tags: javascript, request, fs

```js
let request = require("request")
let fs = require("fs")

let links = [...]
const download = function(uri, filename, callback){
    request.head(uri, function(err, res, body){
  
      request(uri).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename)).on('close', callback)
    })
}

let downloadedImages = 0
for(const url of images){
    let format = url.match(/(png|jpg|webo|jpeg|gif)/)[0]

    download(url, `${downloadedImages}.${format}`, function(){
        console.log(`${downloadedImages}.${format} saved [${downloadedImages}/${images.length}]`)
        downloadedImages = downloadedImages + 1
    })
}
```

for some reason it only downloads the first image of the `links`, it logs `30.jpg saved [30/456]` but i dont see the image anywhere

and the one image that it downloaded is corrupted:
[image]

Comment: What's in `images`?

Comment: an array of image links

Comment: Can you edit and show us the format of that array? Is it `['https://something.tld/image1.jpg']`?

Comment: Should `let links = ...` be `let images = ...`?

Comment: possible your process is exiting before your callbacks are completing?

Comment: `request.head()` just returns the HTTP headers, not the file contents. Use `request.get()`.

Comment: BTW, the `request` module is deprecated. You should use something more modern like Axios.

Comment: alright ill try that

Comment: i used request.get tho it still didnt work @Barmar

Answer (score 0):

So I used anxios and got it working

```js
const axios = require("axios")
const fs = require("fs")

let links = [...]
function download(url, filePath){
  return axios(url, {method: 'GET', responseType: "stream"})
  .then( fileResponse => {
    fileResponse.data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filePath + '.' + extension))
    return fileResponse;
  })

}

let downloadedImages = 0
for(const url of links){
    let format = url.match(/(png|jpg|webo|jpeg|gif)/)[0]

    download(url, `${downloadedImages}.${format}`, function(){
        console.log(`${downloadedImages}.${format} saved [${downloadedImages}/${images.length}]`)
        downloadedImages = downloadedImages + 1
    })
}
```

Comment: interesting, since you're calling `download` with a callback that never gets called :p I mean, it'll work, but `downloadImages` will remain at 0